# Is there a higher dimensional Fredkin gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, unitarity

The [Fredkin gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredkin_gate) is CSWAP gate. Given a control register in $0$ or $1$, the gate does nothing or swaps two target registers respectively.

[image]

Is there a higher dimensional version of this gate? I have one d-dimensional control register (this takes values from the set $S = \{1, 2, ... , d\}$) and $d$ target registers. If the control register takes on value $i\in S$, then I would like to swap the first target register with the $i^{th}$ target register.

Comment: @MarkS aren't all swaps (controlled or otherwise) reversible trivially? Or did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question seems to be about a higher-dimensional control, and not about higher-dimensional targets.  For $d=4$, would the following [circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22,%22%E2%97%A6%22,%22Swap%22,%22Swap%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%97%A6%22,%22Swap%22,1,%22Swap%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Swap%22,1,1,%22Swap%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Swap%22,1,1,1,%22Swap%22%5D%5D%7D) work?

[image: HighDimensionalControl]

Furthermore although this wasn't the question asked, one could instead consider another CSWAP gate that has one qubit control, and higher-dimensional qudits that are swapped conditioned on the qubit.  One [example](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Swap%22,1,%22Swap%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22Swap%22,1,%22Swap%22%5D%5D%7D) also for $d=4$ might be below.  The four bottom qubits are to be thought of as two pairs of $4$-dimensional qudits.

[image: Qudit CSWAPs]