# How to generate matrix for swap(a, b) gate for n qubits

Tags: quantum-gate

I am trying to simulate a swap gate that swaps two qubits of indices a and b where there are n qubits total. I understand how to make a truth table and generate a matrix based off of that for each individual case but I'm having trouble implementing a general way to do this for an arbitrary total number of qubits. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to QCSE.  Are you wishing to perform a *controlled* SWAP, that is controlled off of the particular indices $a$ and $b$?  Perhaps this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/is-there-a-higher-dimensional-fredkin-gate) may be of some help.

Comment: by "implementing" do you mean to find a gate decomposition for it?

Comment: If you just had two qubits, do you already know how to perform swap between those two?

Comment: When there are irrelevant qubits, you can perform multiple *SWAP* gates to make the target (or control) qubits adjacent to each other, this won't be of tremendous effort for numerical computation

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are trying to figure out a matrix that represents this type of circuit:

[image]

In such case, first realize the decomposition of SWAP gate:

[image]

Therefore, if you know how to implement the circuit below then you will pretty much done.

[image]

To implement the circuit above, recall the definition of $CNOT_{1,2}$ (The first qubit is the controlled and the second qubit is the target):

$$ CNOT_{1,2} = |0\rangle \langle 0| \otimes I +  |1 \rangle \langle 1| \otimes X  $$

But here we wanted to implement $CNOT_{2,4}$ instead since the second qubit is the controlled and the fourth qubit is the target.  In such case, you can write it as

$$ CNOT_{2,4} = I \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0| \otimes I \otimes I +  I \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 1| \otimes I \otimes X $$

Also note that by definition:

$$ CNOT_{2,1} = I \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0 | + X \otimes |1\rangle \langle 1 |$$

I think you can finish it off now.