# Matrix representation of multi-qubit operations when there's irrelevant qubit(s)

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

[image: The corresponding gates]

Suppose there are three qubits, q0, q1, and q2, if you perform a *CX* on q0 and q1, the entire matrix of the operation you performed on the whole quantum circuit will simply be the tensor product of *CX* and *I*.

My  question is, how to do so if the irrelevant qubit is between the involved qubits? I have listed three such gates in the upper figure, one *CX* and two *CSWAP*s.

P.S. If you do some *SWAP*s such case can be fixed, but is there a simpler, and more general method?

Comment: See this: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24051/9858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CNOT gate is $|0\rangle \langle0|\otimes I +|1\rangle \langle1|\otimes X$. If there is an intermediary qubit between it then it will simply be $$CNOT_{1,3}=|0\rangle \langle0|\otimes I \otimes I +|1\rangle \langle1| \otimes I\otimes X$$

The same logic extends to all other control gates.

Comment: Maybe you can stress that any quantum logical gates can be decomposed to a set of universal quantum gates, for example, $R_x (θ), R_y (θ), R_z (θ), P(ϕ)$  and $CNOT$